# Converting exr frames to mp4 has scrambled frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have an exr frame sequence that I would like to convert to an mp4 or mov.  The frames are in proper order and I can play the sequence properly in any image sequence player such as mplay or nuke.

The result I'm getting out of `ffmpeg` and/or `ffplay` looks like this:
https://youtu.be/HJxz_P-5xCk

As you can see there are some flickering black frames and it looks like the frames lose their proper order.

The commands I tried are:

`ffmpeg -i squishy_toys.%04d.exr squishy_toys.mov`

`ffmpeg -y -r 24/1 -apply_trc iec61966_2_1 -i squishy_toys.%04d.exr -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=24,format=yuv420p" -movflags faststart "squishy_toys.mp4"`

Both commands generate the disordered mp4 or mov

Comment: For testing, try converting from EXR to PNG sequence: `ffmpeg -i squishy_toys.%04d.exr squishy_toys_%04d.png` and from PNG to MOV: `ffmpeg -i squishy_toys_%04d.png squishy_toys.mov`

Comment: png to mov still doesn't work.  For what it's worth, this image sequence converts nicely to mp4 in windows but not mac or ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please share the PNG image files (use Google Drive for example)? Are you getting the same result when converting to PNG in Windows and from PNG to MP4 in Linux?

Comment: Here's a onedrive link [PNG Frames](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtbhLek9aJLnie4-9r_MtiMN5Gm4-Q?e=U9Nn3p)

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in FFmpeg versions before version 6.0. Using FFmpeg version 6.0, the video looks fine. For Windows FFmpeg 6.0 may be downloaded from [here](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds). For other OS, I don't know.

Comment: I had ffmpeg 4.2 (latest version for ubuntu 22.04),  updated to version 6 for [ubuntu] (https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/03/ffmpeg-6-0-released-how-to-install-in-ubuntu-22-04-20-04)  Problem Solved!! Thanks so much.